# Relabeling the legend in Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

this is my first question, so please do not stone me to death :D
I am running a smarthome stack containing mqtt, telegraf, influxdb2 and grafana8 using bme280 sensors.
everything is running smoothly after some problems but i am having some issues renaming the legend in my grafana dashboard.

my flux query

```
from(bucket: "bme280")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mqtt_consumer")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["topic"] == "sensors/bk/temp" or r["topic"] == "sensors/sz/temp" or r["topic"] == "sensors/wz/temp")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

results in a nice graph however i don't like the legend which is

```
- value {host="raspi", topic="sensors/bk/temp"}
- value {host="raspi", topic="sensors/sz/temp"}
- value {host="raspi", topic="sensors/wz/temp"}
```

it should display

```
- Temperature Balcony
- Temperature Sleeping room
- Temperature living room
```

i can get around changing the "value" tag to something else using

```
|> set(key: "value", value: "temperature")
```

but the part in "{}" is not covered. Is tehre any way to remove this part or at least change it?
[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcYIb.png)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for my by trying the below under  Edit Panel-> Transform, in this case type_instance is the column that had the labels I wanted to use as legend

Add Transform as shown here on Grafana Edit Panel:

[image: Screenshot of the edit panel]